# Trigger Bootstrap modal from disabled textbox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I want to Trigger boot-strap model on click of disabled text-box or text Area
I have tried it but it works fine with text box if the text box enabled

```
<input type="text" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" disabled="disabled"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Disabled elements don't fire click event on all the browsers, or all the inputs.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click

Try this:

```
<span class="disabled">
 <input type="text" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" disabled="disabled"/>
</span>
```

Javascript:

```
$('span.disabled').on('click', function(event) {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

OR if you want to collect the target from the input:

```
$('span.disabled').on('click', function(event) {
    var modal_target = $(this).find('input').data('target');
    $(modal_target).modal('show');
});
```